# Does light absorption result in a momentarily weaker bond?

Tags: bond, quantum-chemistry, spectroscopy, molecular-orbital-theory

I may have just misunderstood the topic, but light absorption by a molecule is a result of a promotion of an electron into an empty antibonding orbital; hence, does that mean that the strength of the bond is momentarily weakened by absorption of light? What processes account for the actual radiation part (release of heat) associated with the absorption of light?

http://www.chemguide.co.uk/analysis/uvvisible/bonding.html

Comment: Well, the electron is in a different orbital (has an excited wave function) - that required an input of energy in to the bound system. The energy difference between the excited state and the ground state may either move to a different electron on the molecule, be re-radiated as a photon, go in to vibration or rotation modes, or some combination of all of those.

Comment: Right, but since the excited wave function is antibonding, does that mean that the bond is weakened until the electron can return to ground state?

Comment: Kind of by definition, yes. The binding energy of the molecule as a whole is reduced by the energy of the absorbed photon. Of course, certain photon energies will result in the molecule falling apart  (which is a clear indication of the bond being weaker!).

Comment: @JohnSmith Depends. Some molecules exists only in excited states.

Comment: Woah, I have never heard of an entire molecule falling apart from interactions with light. Could you give me an example?

Comment: @JohnSmith https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diazirine#Chemistry . Again, excitation may lead to strengthenning of a bond.

Comment: Good as the example is, I'd rather point out that **any** molecule can fall apart from interactions with light, given that photons have enough energy. Also, the orbital from which an electron is excited is not necessarily bonding, and the one to which it gets promoted is not necessarily antibonding, so yes, in some (relatively rare) cases certain kind of excitation can make a bond stronger rather than weaker.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Not entirely correct. One-photon adsorption results in one-electron excitation. If a bond has order more than one, one-electronexcitation can't reduce it's order to zero. There is quite a set of molecules with double and triple bonds. (though gamma-photon interacting with a nuclei of the molecule will surely break it apart, as the energy is extremely high. But it's beyond chemistry)

Comment: @permeakra You are right about the multiple bonds. But wait, your very example shows how **two** separate bonds can be broken simultaneously in a single-photon process.

Comment: @IvanNeretin That's because  the example is kind'a special case. Typically, when photolysis is employed, the molecule in question is inherently unstable towards fragmentation, so even slight change in bonding causes fragmentation. The example molecule has 1) high strain and 2) double N=N bond. It is already ready to break and does so from a funny look.

Comment: True. So let's add the word "almost" to my statement, since almost all molecules have single bonds somewhere. As for those which do not... well, I'm not quite sure whether or not $\ce{CO2}$ can be broken by a single-electron excitation.

Comment: Another thing to consider - don't think just of 'orbitals' - the electronic states of a molecule are more distributed than around a lone atom. By moving an electron to a different state, you have changed the total electron density function, which could impact the molecule as a whole. An analogy is defect levels  (like the As interstitial in GaAs) in semiconductors - if you change the charge state by electron capture, the atomic positions of the interstitial and surrounding lattice atoms changes. Similarly, exciting an electron may result in a different configuration for the entire molecule.

Comment: Molecules dissociating with light is very common, Oxygen & Ozone by UV in the atmosphere, for example, or Iodine vapour by blue-green light (<  approx 500nm), or chlorine by shorter wavelengths.  The molecule NO has a shorter bond length in some of its excited states than it has in its ground state, indicating stronger bonding even though it will have absorbed about 5 eV of energy.

Comment: I think the most general answer to this question: depends on the system.  The ground and excited-states are characterized by orthogonal eigenfunctions (wavefunctions) of the Hamiltonian.  Each wf has an associated electron density matrix/function/distrobution which describes the density of electrons in 3-dimensional space.  It is the distribution of electrons relative to the nuclei which determines how some bonds may strengthen and others weaken upon excitation. @JonCuster is right to remind us that orbital-to-orbital single electron excitation is a drastic simplificaiton for many systems.

Answer (score 1):

it may happen but it is not always necessary as 1S antibonding molecular orbital is lower in energy as compared to 2S bonding MO If electron jumps from 1S ABMO to 2S BMO  then BOND ORDER willhence bond will become stronger increase **`σ(1s) <σ∗(1s) < σ(2s) <σ∗(2s) < π(2px) = π(2py)`** [image]